# Mostrar por ordem alphabetica tabela

Tags: php

Quero mostrar por ordem afabetica o conteúdo de uma coluna de uma tabela cm SQL. Por exemplo experimentei isto mas so me retorne dois registo, enquanto que tenho bem mais, o nombreid contem o COUNT da base de dados.

```
$y='a';     
    //for table users
    for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
    {       
        $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i) AND nom LIKE '$y%'";   
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();//  tableau 'affiche'

        if($affiche['id']!=0)
        {
            //write data 

            echo "<tr class=event bgcolor=$couleur align=left style='font-size:12px;font-family:helvetica'>\n";

            echo "<td title=\"$lib_id\"><a href=_compil_vcf.php?id=$affiche[id]>$affiche[id]</a></td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_nom\">$affiche[nom]</td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_prenom\">$affiche[prenom]</td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_fonction\">$affiche[fonction]</td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_societe\">$affiche[societe]</td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_mobile\">$affiche[mobile]</td>\n";
            echo "<td title=\"$lib_mail\"><a href=mailto:$affiche[mail] title=\"$clic_for_mail\" >$affiche[mail]</a></td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n"; 

            $couleur = get_couleur_fond($couleur,$couleur1,$couleur2);// change de couleur de fond
            $y++;
        }
```

Comment: Já tento ordenar com o `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Sim experimentei com ORDER BY prenom, mas mostra me sempre a ordem por ID.

Comment: $requete="SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i) ORDER BY 'prenom'";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O certo seria você ordenar antes, na lista que pega os IDs.

Mas se for usar técnica XGH pra resolver o problema, pode guardar num *array* os dados, e ordenar pra mostrar:

```
$affiche_tab = array();
$affiche_ord = array();

// Pega todos e reserva

for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
{       
    $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i) AND nom LIKE '$y%'";   
    $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
    $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();//  tableau 'affiche'

    if($affiche['id']!=0)
    {
        $affiche_tab[] = $affiche;
        $affiche_ord[] = $affiche['prenom']; //Aqui voce escolhe a ordem
    }
}

// Agora ordena
array_multisort( $affiche_ord, SORT_ASC, $affiche_tab ); 

// E mostra
foreach( $affiche_tab as $affiche ){
    echo "<tr class=event bgcolor=$couleur align=left style='font-size:12px;font-family:helvetica'>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_id\"><a href=_compil_vcf.php?id=$affiche['id']>$affiche['id']</a></td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_nom\">$affiche['nom']</td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_prenom\">$affiche['prenom']</td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_fonction\">$affiche['fonction']</td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_societe\">$affiche['societe']</td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_mobile\">$affiche['mobile']</td>\n";
    echo "<td title=\"$lib_mail\"><a href=mailto:$affiche['mail'] title=\"$clic_for_mail\" >$affiche['mail']</a></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
    $couleur = get_couleur_fond($couleur,$couleur1,$couleur2);// change de couleur de fond
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, como posso passar uma variavel para alterar o $affiche['prenom'], a partir de um link. Para que depois a função de para ordenar os campos da tabela. Por exemplo "<td><a href=?prenom=prenom>prenom</td>\n";

Comment: Só trocar o `$affiche['prenom']` por `$affiche[$ordem]` e o `$ordem` você envia com valores diferentes: `?ordem=prenom`, `?ordem=nom`, ... (se estiver usando $_GET, senão precisa por como valor de um botão ou campo de FORM)

Comment: Tenho a minha hyperlink <a href=?variable=$prenom> e chamo por GET o codigo. Defino $prenom='prenom' e altero $affiche_ord[] = $affiche[$prenom]; e para os outros campos, tambem tenho um hyperlink. Mas tenho de repetir o codigo.

Comment: não é $affiche[$prenom], é $affiche[$ordem]. você muda só o valor de ordem no html, não no PHP. É só `<a href="?ordem=prenom">`, `<a href="?ordem=nom">`, etc. Não tem que por variável no HTML.

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente, o unico problema é que tenho alguns dados que começam por letra minusculas, e assim ficam no fim da tabela. Como posso resolver isso.

Comment: Onde está `$affiche_ord[] = $affiche['prenom'];` você acrescenta o `strtoupper()`, ficando assim: `$affiche_ord[] = strtoupper( $affiche['prenom'] );` - Mas só nessa linha. Não precisa mexer na que tem `$affiche_tab`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a consulta dessa forma:

```
$requete= "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i) ORDER BY prenom ASC";
```

Dessa forma vai ordernar pelo campo prenom de forma ascendente, se quiser descendente é só mudar por:

```
$requete= "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i) ORDER BY prenom DESC";
```

Comment: Não me funciona, continua sempre a mostra-me por ordem de ID.

Comment: Poderia mostrar a estrutura da sua tabela?

Comment: Ah, entendi o porque tá dando erro. Você não vai conseguir ordernar por nome, porque ta fazendo uma consulta a cada laço do loop, então em cada query que você faz, você ta recebendo apenas um registro. Ta ordenando pelo ID porque ta sendo pela orden do for. A cada loop do for você traz um registro e exibe ele. O certo seria você trazer tudo, sem o WHERE na query, e depois usar um foreach pra poder percorrer toda a consulta.

Comment: Certo entendi, como posso então fazer?

Comment: No momento não tenho como fazer, mas olha esse link e veja como faz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547416/how-select-rows-from-database-mysql-with-foreach - Você vai criar a SQL e depois usar um foreach para percorrer toda o resultado. Olha a resposta marcada como certa nessa pergunta ai.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo assim:

```
<?php
    //retorna a consulta ordenada já
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY prenom";

    //executa a query
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    //percorre as posições da consulta
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<td title=\"$lib_nom\">$row[nom]</td>\n";
    }
?>
```